# How to resolve UnsatisfiedLinkError when using JNI with packages?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Firstly, my example has the following directory structure:

```
Sample.c
lib/
mypackage/
--Sample.java
```

`Sample.java` in `mypackage` looks like this:

```
package mypackage;

public class Sample {
    public static native int sampleMethod(int x);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("Sample");
        System.out.println("sampleMethod result: " + sampleMethod(5));
    }
}
```

I run `javac mypackage/Sample.java` to compile the java file and `javah mypackage.Sample` to generate the `JNI` headers. Then I compile the library using the following command:

```
clang -I"${JAVA_HOME}/include" -I"${JAVA_HOME}/include/darwin" -o lib/libSample.so -shared Sample.c
```

At this point the directory structure looks like this:

```
Sample.c
mypackage_Sample.h
lib/
--libSample.so
mypackage/
--Sample.java
--Sample.class
```

Now when I try to run the example using `java -Djava.library.path=./lib/ mypackage.Sample` I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no Sample in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at mypackage.Sample.main(Sample.java:7)
```

I tried specifying the full path to `lib/`, but I get the same error.

I am not sure if the code for the header and the implementation matter, but I will post them anyway.

`mypackage_Sample.h`:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class mypackage_Sample */

#ifndef _Included_mypackage_Sample
#define _Included_mypackage_Sample
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     mypackage_Sample
 * Method:    sampleMethod
 * Signature: (I)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_mypackage_Sample_sampleMethod
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

`Sample.c`:

```
#include "mypackage_Sample.h"
#include <stdio.h>

JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_mypackage_Sample_sampleMethod
  (JNIEnv * env, jclass obj, jint num) {
      return num * num;
  }
```

I run this on `OS X Yosemite 10.10.5` using `clang 7.0.2` and `java 1.8.0_101`.

Comment: You probably have the wrong library name, you can find out what you need with `System.mapLibraryName("Sample");`. I Think it should be `Sample.dylib` on OSX, not `libSample.so`.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know about that and it solved the problem. It was `libSample.dylib`. You can write it as an answer.

Comment: Done, (I probably should have done that in the first place :).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the wrong name from your library file (`libSample.so`).

If you use:

```
System.loadLibrary("Sample");
```

The JVM will map this name to a platform specific file name to try and load. On Linux that is `libSample.so`, on Windows that is `Sample.dll`, but on OS X it's something else.

You can find out which name your library file should have by looking at the output of:

```
System.mapLibraryName("Sample");
```

Called on the target platform.

After that, you can use that as the name of your library file.

Comment: Once again thank you! I was deluded by an article stating that the library name is `lib<name>.so` for all `UNIX`-based systems. `mapLibraryName` really resolved the issue.